# How to select Rows in a Data Frame from one Value (name to name) to another

Tags: r, dataframe, select, rows

I need help with a data.frame!
I have the data set :"BostonHousing2" from the package "mlbench". I need a subset that selects the rows from the value "Sargus" until the last observation of city "Melrose" (both are in the first column of the set). How can I write this?

My first try:

```
BH2 <- BostonHousing2[1,"Sargus":"Melrose"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should post what you have tried to get some assistance.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. That is why I didn't put anything.

Comment: Instead of being mean in your comments you could try to help who actually requires help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the row numbers of Sargus and Melrose.

```
library(mlbench)
library(tidyverse)

data("BostonHousing2")

BostonHousing2[min(which(BostonHousing2$town == "Sargus")):max(which(BostonHousing2$town == "Melrose")), ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A very clear and simple response! <3

Comment: No problem. If my answer was helpful, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but you could do by noting the the tract numbers for Sargus and Melrose.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing2) 

df<-BostonHousing2 %>%
  filter(tract %>% between(2081,3364))
```